# Saving file: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I am creating a simple windows application using VS2012 and on windows 8.
There is a rich text box in which user should enter text, and when the form is closed, it should save the text of the richtextbox in a file. However, Almost always application is throwing error saying that the file that is "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"
The code is as below

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            richTextBox1.LoadFile("D:\\MyNotes\\MyNotes.rtf");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            System.IO.File.Create("D:\\MyNotes\\MyNotes.rtf");
        }
    }
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {


        try
        {

            System.IO.StreamWriter SW = new System.IO.StreamWriter(
            "D:\\MyNotes\\MyNotes.rtf", false, Encoding.ASCII);
            SW.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
            SW.Close();

                            //Even this does not work
            // richTextBox1.SaveFile("D:\\MyNotes\\MyNotes.rtf");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

Comment: @CodeCaster True, but the exact answer is provided here. The details about why it is really like this, is here. So I think this is the better to understand and implement

Comment: When your question is close-voted as duplicate, it means the principle of your question is already answered elsewhere on this site, namely in the question yours is marked a duplicate of. While the surroundings may differ from question to question, you're not the only one who calls `File.Create()` and forgets to close the handle that returns.

Comment: So should I delete this question?

Comment: No,just wait for it to be closed. Your wording or that of the answers may help future visitors who arrive here through the search. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at MSDN, you will see that the [File.Create method returns a FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx).

In your `try..catch`, you are creating a file using `File.Create` but leaving the `FileStream` hanging.

Change it to something like this:

```
if (!File.Exists("D:\\MyNotes\\MyNotes.rtf")) {
    using (var stream = File.Create("D:\\MyNotes\\MyNotes.rtf")) {
        // nop
    }
}
```

.. or calling `Close()`.

This explains the "almost always".. because when you run it again the file is created and the block doesn't run.

You may consider not creating the file at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create("D:\\MyNotes\\MyNotes.rtf");
fs.Close();
```

System.IO.File.Create() had your file open all along.

Answer (score 0):

The [File.Create Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File.Create.aspx) returns a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) (more specifically a [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx), and that type implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IDisposable.aspx). Whenever you get an IDisposable it is important that you dispose it as appropriate. Since you don't dispose the object returned by File.Create, you get the exception.

Often when reading/writing files you can achieve what you want using the methods [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) and [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File.WriteAllText.aspx) which are easier to work with in this regard since they don't return IDisposable objects.

In your case I see no reason to use the methods returning IDisposable objects, just use File.ReadAllText and File.WriteAllText. Explained in another way: You don't need the streams, you simply want to read/write text.

Actually you don't even need File.ReadAllText:

```
public class Form1
{
    private const string fileName = @"D:\MyNotes\MyNotes.rtf";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            File.WriteAllText(fileName, "");

        richTextBox1.LoadFile(fileName);
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.SaveFile(fileName);
    }
}
```